# Why is my server's physical memory 1 MB?

Tags: memory

When I opened up System Information on my Windows 7 computer and queried my older (~2005) server, the following erroneous information appeared:

[image: Total Physical Memory: 1.00 MB]

Why is my total physical memory `1.00 MB` instead of `1.00 GB`? Moreover, why can't my installed RAM be detected?

Comment: How did you query it? What os is the other server?

Comment: @CanadianLuke msinfo32 lets you connect to another computer. This server is running Windows Server 2003 (yes I know it's old, but it's not being used for production, and it's 32-bit).